# I am trying to store my values of entry widget into a list using a 'submit button', but its showing error using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, jupyter

```
from tkinter import * // Libraries imported
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
ROOT = tk.Tk()
strong textROOT.withdraw()

root = Tk()
s=[]                       //empty list to append entry values
i=0                        // to iterate over for loop 
for y in range(5):
   r= Label(root, text="file_"+str(y)).grid(row=i)   //5-labels created using for loop
   i=i+1
   i=0
for y in range(5):
   r=("file_"+str(y))                          //5 entry boxes created using for loop
   r = Entry(root)
   r.grid(row=i , column=1)
   i=i+1
def getInput():
    for y in range(5):                             //entry value is stored 
        r = ("file_"+str(y))
        b = r.get()
        s.append(b)
        root.destroy()
Button(root, text = "submit",command = getInput).grid(row = 5, sticky = W) 
                   //click  box 'submit' is created to store values into empty list 's'//
mainloop()                                             //code ends
```

//The code is showing error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get
//I am not able to store my entry values into an empty list S and later retrieve the entry values of that list.

Comment: this is not python - `# this is a comment`

Comment: `i=i+1` followed by  `i=0` makes no sense - please provide a [mre]

Comment: Ok , I am new to python , Thanks for the suggestion. can you help me with that code ?

Answer (score 1):

`r = ("file_"+str(y))` followed by `b = r.get()` won't magically retrieve the contents of the widget. You need to store your `Entry` widgets in a container like a `list`.

You could also get rid of the 2nd loop - why don't create both `Label` and `Entry` in the same loop?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entries = []

for y in range(5):
    tk.Label(root, text="file_"+str(y)).grid(row=y,column=0)
    r = tk.Entry(root)
    r.grid(row=y,column=1)
    entries.append(r)

def getInput():
    print ([ent.get() for ent in entries])

tk.Button(root, text = "submit", command = getInput).grid(row = 5, sticky = "w")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You bro ! yeah that label and the entry can be in the same loop. ok ! ,